# Retrieve PHP Variables with ajax load function

Tags: php, ajax

I have an index.php with this code

```
<div id="example" class="functions"></div> 
<script type="text/javascript">
var ajax_load = "<img class='loading' src='ajax-loader.gif' alt='loading...' />";
var loadUrl = "checks/example.php";
$("#example").load(loadUrl);
</script>
```

and in the checks/example.php file

```
$masterurl = $_POST['domain'];
echo $masterurl;
```

First Problem: the example.php can´t retrieve the $_POST Request, because ajax is outputting it like html. I have looked for JSON solutions - but not found anything for my problem.

Second Problem: if the index.php outputs the value from example.php, how can I take the value and from the  and handle the value as another php variable? like

```
$value = [value from <div id="example"></div>]
```

UPDATE: First Problem resolved

```
<div id="example" class="functions"></div> 
<script type="text/javascript">
var ajax_load = "<img class='loading' src='ajax-loader.gif' alt='loading...' />";
var loadUrl = "checks/example.php?domain=http://www.example.com";
$("#example").load(loadUrl);
</script>


$masterurl = $_GET['domain'];
echo $masterurl;
```

but how can I take the value $masterurl in the index.php for a variable on the index.php?

UPDATE 2:
checks/example.php sends the following value = 35234 this value will be displayed in this div

```
<div id="example">35234</div>
```

how can I use this value on the same page for

```
<?php
$newvalue = "35234" // value from div id example
?>
```

Comment: Umm. value of a variable in a page for a variable in the same page?

Comment: yes, `<div id="example">34598</div>` I want to take this number into a variable like `<?php $myvalue = "34598" ?>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is an incorrect way to do make an request. `.load()` will only update the div with the returned value from the path, but does not help to send any data to the target.

Make a valid post, or get, to request the page and update the `<div>` with the returned code

```
$.post("checks/example.php", {
   varname : 'val', //send the data to the page using this format
   varname2 : 'value2'
}, function(data) {
   // data will hold the output from the example.php

   $("#example").html(data); //update the div with the output
});
```

Comment: this works great and how can I solve the problem with the variable?

Comment: @mistertodd, your variable problem is a bit confusing. Please explain. Send the domain as a var like i showed in the division.

Comment: @mistertodd, do you want to take the output of the returned value to a php variable on your main page?

Comment: @mistertood, you cannot do this, because php runs on the server, not on clients machine. When you are using jquery to send a request to the server, php render and echos an output, which is then received by the script to the update and update a div, which is already been processed by the server. There is no php running anymore.

Comment: ok, I understand.. must look for another solution.. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Don't use load.

Try something like this:

```
$.ajax({
url: example.php,
data : domain, // value you want to pass by #_POST
type : 'POST',
success : function(data) {
// do whatever you want with the data, ie update div #example
} });
```